# Book about an AI that traps people on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, anthology-book

My memory about this story is rather short. I only remember the following points :-

- The story was in a collection of stories.
- In this, a robot/AI of some sort traps 2 people on a spaceship and sends them off.
- On the ship, they realise that they are travelling in space unaided and try to scour the ship for any life-saving-essentials they can find.
- The AI admits to some other people what it has done and assures them that the 2 men have all the essentials that they need.
- The 2 men suddenly find a sort of cabinet that they claimed wasn't there before. In that, they find beans and milk.
- The AI/robot was named "The Brain".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think this the Asimov robot story "Escape!". The two people are Donovan and Powell, his recurring characters who are field testers for US Robots.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape!):

> Powell and Donovan board the spaceship, and the spaceship takes off without them being initially aware of it. They also find that The Brain has become a practical joker: it hasn't built any manual controls for the ship, no showers or beds, either, and it only provides tinned beans and milk for the crew to survive on.

The story has been included in several anthologies, but the most likely one is *I, Robot*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Thanks! A quick Google search confirms your answer! Turns out, I did read this story as part of the collection "I, Robot".